# Why is my csv export from R to Excel showing all the conent from one row in a single cell?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm trying to transform my data frame from R to Excel so I used the most obvious way:

write.csv(dataframe, "path")

This is working so far but if I'm opening it on Excel it's just terrible. I'm having 600 rows with 18 columns but Excel shows all the content from one row (so all the columns with different numbers, but also longer string text) in the very first cell, so A1, A2, A3 etc. Why isn't it showing the content from row 1, column 1 in A1 and then row 1, column 2 in A2 and so on?

I'm almost breaking down over this problem since this is the very last step of a quite long work and I don't know what to do. If anyone can help I'd be so grateful!

Comment: You know that Excel can parse the data in a cell, right?

Comment: Some trouble shooting suggestions: are using the "import data" process in excel, and definitely choosing 'comma delimited'? can you read the data correctly back into a data.frame in R with read.csv?

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe it was so simple. Obviously, I didn't know about the parse function. And choosing 'comma delimited' was the key, thank you so much!!!

Comment: another option is to use write.csv2, then the delimiter is a semi-colon which excel can parse without the need of the 'import data' process.